# Merge Dataframes with missing data in either one or the other column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) I want to merge. There is a common key (`id`) to both dataframes. Both dataframes have the columns `Feature1` and `Feature2`. For each id the data belonging to `Feature1` would be either in `df1` or `df2`. The same for the column `Feature2`.

I already tried to merge these dataframes but instead of getting only two columns (three with id) in the final dataframe, I get `Feature1_x` and `Feature1_y` because it recognises np.nan values as a valid value. Is there a way of getting only `Feature1` and `Feature2` without np.nan values?

```py
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': [np.nan, 'C', 'E', np.nan, np.nan],
        'Feature2': ['B', np.nan, np.nan, 'H', 'J']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
dummy_data2 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', np.nan, np.nan, 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': [np.nan, 'D', 'F', np.nan, np.nan]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
```

I expect just getting:

```py
dummy_data12 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J']}
df12 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data12, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If values in `id` are same in both `DataFrame`s and also index are same in both:

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
  id Feature1 Feature2
0  1        A        B
1  2        C        D
2  3        E        F
3  4        G        H
4  5        I        J
```

If not sure possible solution is [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with set index by `id` column in both:

```
df = df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id')).reset_index()
print (df)
  id Feature1 Feature2
0  1        A        B
1  2        C        D
2  3        E        F
3  4        G        H
4  5        I        J
```